# ¿Cúal es el origen de la palabra "holgin"?

Tags: etimología, historia, palabras-raras, diccionarios

La palabra "holgin" no figura actualmente en el DLE, pero si en distintos diccionarios, como el de Covarrubias (1611), en el Diccionario de Autoridades (1734) y otros muchos hasta 1918:
[**Holgin, na**](https://webfrl.rae.es/DA.html)

> Lo mismo que Hechicero.

Curiosamente, a pesar de estar presente en una veintena de diccionarios a lo largo de 300 años, no aparece recogido ningún caso en el [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html) ni en el [Fichero general de la RAE](https://apps2.rae.es/fichero.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que puede derivar de (o evolucionar a) ***[jorguín](https://dle.rae.es/jorgu%C3%ADn?m=form)*** que, según el diccionario de la RAE, significa "persona que hace hechicerías" y deriva del vasco **[sorgin](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgina)**, "bruja".